# What is the numpy way to conditionally merge arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, text-classification

I have two numpy arrays `(1000,)` filled with predictions from two models:

```
pred_1 = model_1.predict(x_test)
pred_2 = model_2.predict(x_test)
```

`model_1` is attractive due to extremely low `FP`, but consequently high `FN`.

`model_2` is attractive due to overall accuracy and recall.

How can I *conditionally* apply predictions to take advantage of these strengths and weaknesses?

I'd like to take all positive (`1`) predictions from the first model, and let the second model deal with the rest.

Essentially I'm looking for something like this:

```
final_pred = model_1.predict() if model_1.predict() > 0.5 else model_2.predict()
```

This fails: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.

What is the numpy way to combine these arrays as above?

Comment: The `if`is a Python operator that only works with whole object, not element by element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`numpy.where`](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
a = model_1.predict(x_test)
b = model_2.predict(x_test)

out = np.where(a > 0.5, a, b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try a list comprehension as following and then cast the list to array using `np.array`. You loop over the independent variable, here `x_test`, and then for each value of `x_test`, you compute the model prediction from two models and depending on the `if` condition, you store the output.

```
final_pred = np.array([model_1.predict(i) if model_1.predict(i) > 0.5 else model_2.predict(i) for i in x_test])
```

---

You can also use NumPy indexing as

```
mask = (pred_1 > 0.5)
pred_2[mask] = pred_1[mask]
final_pred = pred_2
```

Here, you first create a mask where `pred_1 > 0.5`, then use those indices in the `pred_2` array, and replace those values with the values of `pred_1`. The resulting `pred_2` will be your `final_pred`.

Comment: Don't make the same mask twice.  It's inefficient

Comment: Store the mask as a variable, then it's only calculated a single time.